# Push from Device to Device

Tags: android, ios, push, parse-platform

When I want to send a push notification from one device to another, I have just learned, that I need to send the message from the device to a server and the server then will send it to the other device! But to do so, I need two ID's, the App-ID and the Device-ID, right. How is this device-ID generated? Randomly by me? And then, how does it get stored at e.g. parse? Can somebody light my questions?

Comment: Good luck on your homework!